# Hide html tag when browser render

Tags: css

How to hide unnecessary HTML tag when browser renders the page? I'm developing a responsive theme and for now I'm just using `display: none;` to hide all the tags (`<div>/<img>/<span>`). But as I know browser will read all DOM and then apply all rule including CSS and JavaScript.

**css**

```
.desktop {
    display:none;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="desktop">
    <img src= " ..
    <div id="container" ...
    <span class="font ...
</div>
```

So what is correct way to hide unnecessary tags rendered by browser when I'm using same HTML page with same CSS file with responsive mode?

Note : If you using firebug, even if you set with `display:none` browser still load all div including images but just not show to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:none` style to the element you do want to be shown (it will not even flink in the UI), and then remove it using javascript:

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="hideme">Hide me</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("hideme").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine. `display: none;` should do the job. If you are manipulating DOM using JavaScript, you may apply inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some specific elements it is better to set the `style` on the element. since this will this reduces the amount of look up for the CSS engine to find which elements match the CSS selector on a external style sheet. so something like this will do the trick:

`<div id="container" style="display:none"></div>`